# MIPS Assembly Scheduling

Tags: java, mips

I have to read in an assembly text file, and then compute the scheduling requirements of MIPS assembly language programs. I am able to read the file, but am not certain as to how I would be able to schedule the requirements of MIPS. I am writing my program in java.

I am supposed to schedule based on this:

> 1. Instruction fetch (IF):
>      Fetch the instruction pointed to by the PC, and then update the PC by adding 4 to it (since all instructions are exactly 4 bytes long).
> 2. Instruction decode (ID):
>      • Decode the instruction.
>      • Read the registers.
>      • Perform an equality test on the contents of the registers.
>      • Compute the possible branch target address by adding the offset to the incremented PC.
>      • If the equality test is true, and the instruction decodes to a branch instruction, then load the branch target address into the PC.
>      Note that all this can be done in parallel, if the results can be saved in independent registers, and much of it might well turn out to be wasted work that costs power and takes hardware but does not add to the time required.
> 3. Execute (EX):
>      • For a memory reference, add base register and offset to create the effective address.
>      • For an RR instruction, do the operation on the contents read from the registers.
>      • For an RI instruction, do the operation on the contents of R1 and the immediate.
> 4. Memory (MEM):
>      • If the instruction is a load, read from the effective address.
>      • If the instruction is a store, write from register to the effective address.
>      2
> 5. Write back (WB):
>      • For an RR or RI instruction, write the results back into the reg- ister.
>      • For a load instruction, put the fetched memory contents into the register.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
        file = getAssembly(read(args[0]));
        for (int i = 0; i < file.size(); ++i) {
            System.out.println(file.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> read(String filepath) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File(filepath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String st = "";
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            result.add(st);
        }
        br.close();
        return result;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getAssembly(ArrayList<String> input){
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
            if (!input.get(i).contains(".") || input.get(i).contains("#") || input.get(i).contains("\t")) {
                result.add(input.get(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this... this _what_?  Should "_this_" have been a link to an example?

Comment: I want to be able to have my output look like this after I compile the code [Picture](https://imgur.com/a/lgSwO4t).

Comment: sorry I was finding the link to an output example

Comment: The 5 columns at the right of the listing are the schedule?  What do the numbers in those five columns represent?

Comment: Those are all the times that IF, ID, EX, MEM, and WB are being run for each instruction.

Comment: So I believe that I need to take the contents from the file that I read, create a dictionary with all the instructions in it, and then pair the instruction with its type.

Comment: It's going to be that, and probably a lot more, too.  For instance, the first three instructions in the example are `addiu`, `sw`, and `sw`. What is it about `addiu` and `sw` instructions that requires the first `sw` to start at time 3, _three_ ticks after the preceding `addiu`?  And why can the second `sw` tthen start at time 4, just _one_ tick after the preceding `sw`?  That's the kind of information you need to capture in order to figure out a schedule.